# How can I organize my listview based on relevance to a String?

Tags: java, android, listview

I was wondering how can I organinze my listview based on a relevance to a string? Is this possible in Android?

So lets say my results are:

"Hi THERE"
"GOD BLESS H"
"FIND THERE HI"

and the string is "Hi"

it'll organize based on the relevance to the string

Edit 1: 
My Custom ArrayAdapter for the listview:

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<AdapterItem> {
    private List<AdapterItem> items = new ArrayList<AdapterItem>();

    public MyAdapter(Context context, int textviewid) {
            super(context, textviewid);

    }

    public void addAdapterItem(AdapterItem item) {
        items.add(item);
    }

    public int getCount() {
      return items.size();
    }

    @Override
    public AdapterItem getItem(int position) {
            return ((null != items) ? items.get(position) : null);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
      View rowView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.itemview, null);
      TextView firstTextView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
      firstTextView.setText(items.get(position).first);       
      // do the same with second and third
      return rowView;
    }

}
```

My Comparer & AdapterItem

```
public class TComparator implements Comparator<AdapterItem> {
    private final Collator   collator = Collator.getInstance();
    public int compare(AdapterItem ob1, AdapterItem ob2) {
        return  collator.compare(ob1.first, string);
    }
}   

class AdapterItem {
    public String first;
    public String second;
    public String third;
    public int fourth;

    public AdapterItem(String first, String second, String third, int fourth) {
        this.first = first;
        this.second = second;
        this.third = third;
        this.fourth = fourth;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make a heuristic for relevance, then loop through the elements of the adapter, scoring them, then sort them according to score, and then rearrange them in the adapter (or maybe you have to make a new adapter), then set the listview to the new adapter and update.

Seems like a lot of work though... there are built in ways to sort of guess what the person is trying to type, one of which is through the search interface: I'd read about it here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html

EDIT:

Actually, if you use an ArrayAdapter, there is a sort() method where you can use a comparator to sort your adapter: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html

You can use your heuristic as the comparator and sort the adapter that way!

Edit2:

Lets say your ArrayAdapter is of type T, that is your adapter looks like this:

```
ArrayAdapter<T> myAdapter = ...
```

then you do this:

```
public class TComparator implements Comparator<T> {

    public int compare(T ob1, T ob2) {
        if (ob1 is more relevant than ob2) {
            return 1;
        } else if (ob1 is less relevant than ob2) {
            return -1;
        } else (ob1 is of equal relevance to ob2) {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

how you determine relevance is for you to figure out and depends on the task

And then you can simply do

```
myAdapter.sort(new TComparator());
```

and that sorts the adapter

Comment: I currently use a Base Adapter with my own class cause I have multiple items in there. Is there any easy way to convert it to a ArrayAdapter so I can easily sort it.

Comment: Well, ArrayAdapter is a subclass of BaseAdapter, so I would just change the static type and instantiation of what you're using now to ArrayAdapter and it will work

Comment: I got it is there a example of a sort in a custom array adapter?

Comment: I tried that but it seems to not work:  public class TComparator implements Comparator<AdapterItem> {
     public int compare(AdapterItem ob1, AdapterItem ob2) {
         if (ob1.first.compareTo(ob2.first) > 0) {
             return 1;
         } else if (ob1.first.compareTo(ob2.first) < 0) {
             return -1;
         } else {
             return 0;
         }
     }
 } it doesn't work :s

Comment: maybe you can edit your original question with the actual code.. it would make it easier to read, and include what your AdapterItem is

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8099/discussion-between-benoir-and-user1104659)